# onRequestPermissionsResult is not called in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, permissions

I have a `CompatActivity` and `v4CompatFragment` in it. I'm trying to request `permissions` from `Fragment` and get the result in `Fragment` too.

Here's my code: that's how I'm requesting permissions:

```
    private void checkSmsPermissions() {
        requestPermissions(new String[] {Manifest.permission.RECEIVE_SMS}, REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_RECEIVE_SMS);
   }
```

That's how I'm trying to get the result, but my code never goes into this method:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSION_RECEIVE_SMS:
            //do something
            break;
    }
}
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: did you add this permission in manifest also

Comment: Have you try with FragmentCompat.requestPermissions() ?

Comment: Override the onRequestPermissionResult in you activity. This is where the result will be handled. You can create a function in your Fragment and call it inside the  onRequestPermissionResult  of your activity

Comment: Have you declare permission in Android Manifest ? and before request any run time permission you should check first required permission is already granted or not if not then request for it.

Comment: @Ratilal Chopda, yes I did.

Comment: Are you overriding `onRequestPermissionsResult` in the activity to which the fragment is attached?

Comment: @Haresh Chhelana, I have no this class..

Comment: @Vodet nope, this is not the solution. I know I could use the ActivityCompat.requestPermissions if I'd like to get result in Activity.

Comment: @clownba0t why do I need it? Anyway, I tried and I'm getting wrong requestCode in Activity and onRequestPermissionsResult wasn't called in Fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found where was my problem hiding.

I have a `BaseActivity` and I extend every other Activity from it. BaseActivity had a `onRequestPermissionsResult` method without calling `super`.